# How can I configure nginx to reroute https to https with port number

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

How can I configure nginx to reroute from a user browser visiting `https://abc.example.com` to `https://abc.example.com:8025`.

1. /etc/hosts:
   abc.example.com   ==> nginx server
2. telnet connection is successful to 192.168.1.10 8025
3. Getting a **502 Bad Gateway** error when visiting: `https://abc.example.com`

nginx.conf file:

```
upstream backend_site {
    hash $remote_addr;
    server 192.168.1.10:8025;
}

server {
    server_name abc.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_site
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = abc.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name abc.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```